# Quasar 2 Vue 3 "ReferenceError: process is not defined" error

Tags: vuejs2, environment-variables, nullreferenceexception, quasar-framework, quasar

I bump into `ReferenceError: process is not defined` error for my Quasar 2 application deployed to firebase. Howver, running it locally with `quasar dev` does not see the error. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env#caveats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing NPM `process` package.

Comment: FWIW, I has this issue which was caused by invalid import statements at the top of the Vue SFC pointed to by router.js, the imports has been added automatically by VS Code, removing these removed the errror.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well after I accidentally ran "quasar build" in my functions directory rather than in my root directory then deployed that.

Easy way to test this is run the build command in the root directory and check if it fixes the error on the firebase hosting emulator (usually localhost:5000) before deploy.

Hope this helps anyone else who has my issue.